# c tree structure expression must have a class type

Tags: c, class, types, expression

I am writing a binary tree program where each node contains a struct. Being new to pointers, I am not sure how to fix this error I am getting.

These are my structs:

```
//inventory definition
typedef struct inventory
{
    char invName[36];
    int  invPartNo;
    int  invQOH;
    float invUnitCost;
    float invPrice;
}item;

//tree definition
struct btree {
    item *data;
    struct btree *left;
    struct btree *right;
} ;
```

And in these two functions, I am getting the 'expression must have a class type' error:

```
struct btree *binary_search(struct btree *tree, int data)
{
    if (tree==NULL) return NULL;
    else if (data == tree->data.invPartNo) //tree in this line is highlighted red with the error
        return tree;
    else if (data < tree->data.invPartNo) //tree in this line is highlighted red with the error
        return(binary_search(tree->left, data));
    else
        return(binary_search(tree->right, data));
}


btree *Insert(btree *node, inventory i)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        btree *temp;
        temp = (btree *)malloc(sizeof(btree));
        temp->data = i;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    if(i.invPartNo > node->data.invPartNo) //node is highlighted with error
    {
        node->right = Insert(node->right, i);
    }
    else if(i.invPartNo < node->data.invPartNo) //node is highlighted with error
    {
        node->left = Insert(node->left, i);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: The member `data` is a pointer. There are some other inconsistencies in your code (like using `inventory` as a type), are you sure you're programming C and not C++? Also, there are some other errors I'm surprised you don't ask about (like assigning a non-pointer structure to a pointer to structure).

Comment: `data == (tree->data)->invPartNo`..after all `data` is pointer in node

Comment: Please, don't cast the return value of `malloc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node->data` is a *pointer* to an `item` type, so `.` is not suitable for it when trying to select a sub-field.

You need to use `->`, as in `(node->data)->invPartNo`.

But I'm not entirely sure *why* you would separate the payload into another structure <sup>(a)</sup>. I'd probably make it all *one* structure and then just use manipulation of the pointers for tree re-structuring. In other words, something like:

```
struct btree {
  item data;           // Now it IS "node->data.something".
  struct btree *left;
  struct btree *right;
};
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There are sometimes valid reasons for this such as if the btree payload is yet another collection like a linked list, or if you want the trees to be able to store arbitrary data types. But it appears here that it would be a lot simpler to only have one level of indirection, that of the tree nodes themselves.